Will a replicated event cause issues?
I've got the replication configuration shown in the image. Everything replicates to everywhere. One of the tables maintains session data which has rows that must be deleted due to expiration. I created an event that checks for expired sessions once per day and deletes them:
DELETE FROM session 
WHERE expiration < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 7200);

My questions are these:

Will this lead to an unstable condition where each of the databases is (near) simultaneously executing the event and at the same time attempting to replicate the updates?
If so, can an event be restricted to a single database instance with SQL or via some other means?
Is an event even the proper tool for this job?

Note that Site A and Site B are physically separate (USA east and west coasts) so there is network delay.
Edit: This is MySQL 8.0.36


DELETE FROM session 
WHERE expiration < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 7200)
  AND @@server_id = 1234567;

Each MySQL instance in the replica-set must have a unique server_id (read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_id).
The number 1234567 above is just an example. You would replace this with the server_id used on one of your MySQL instances.
This will make the condition of your DELETE statement false for all rows, unless the event is executing on one specific instance that matches the server_id.
You might like to make this data-driven, by storing the server_id value in a table, and coding your event so it reads the value from that table. Then you could easily switch which instance will run the DELETE, by updating the value in the table. You could also disable deletions temporarily by setting the value to a number that does not match any of the server_id of your replica-set.

That's what I was looking for.  Thanks Bill.
